# request-promise post request to axios request

Tags: node.js, axios, request-promise

Can you please help me convert the following request to axios request.

```
const request = require('request-promise');

const data = {name:'pte', age:30}
const options = {secret:'34444'}
const opp = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://something',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    options,
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
};

return request(opp);
```

Comment: Are you using it to request an `aws` service?

Comment: Yes @eol. The gateway is running on AWS

Comment: `{secret:'34444'}` are the only options you pass? There should also be `key` in this config object. Also are you using `aws4` or `aws2` ?

Comment: Am using p12 digital certificate, am not sure the contents in it. `aws2`

Comment: Hmm, but how do you pass the cert to the request-module?

Comment: Its part of `options` `const options = {secret:'34444, cert: theFilePointer}`,

Answer (score 1):

```
const axios = require('axios')

const url = 'https://something'
const data = { name : 'pte', age : 30 }
const options = {
   headers : {
      'content-type' : 'application/json'
   }
}

axios.post(url, data, header)
```

Comment: That was my first though but i got fail, since am accessing a particular gateway, but with request-promise the way it is, all goes well.